# require_once() cant find the include path

Tags: php, apache, drupal, xampp

Hi i am trying to indlude a file by using require_once(). i am using xampp apache php server. 
the file test.php is in htdocs drupal folder is also in the same directory where the include files is.
the code in line 5 is

require_once ‘drupal7/includes/bootstrap.inc’;

i am getting error

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\import.php on line 5

Warning: require_once(inc’) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\import.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'inc’' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\import.php on line 5

someone please guide me how to include a local file.

Comment: You say `test.php`, but the errors say `import.php`.  Are these the same file?

Comment: sorry my mistake its only one file import.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have "fancy" single quotes in line 5. (Did you copy this from somewhere?) Change them to regular single quotes, like these:

```
require_once 'drupal7/includes/bootstrap.inc';
```

Comment: i copied it from notepad++ where i wrote this code. the path is in my local machine i am using xampp apache php server. i did not understand your answer it is single quote and you want me to change it to single code. sorry. any help would be appreciate

Comment: Your line 5 seems to have quotes that curl, at least as far as I can see here on SO. Try using what I put in my freshly-edited answer.

Comment: thanks u saved me. i did not even notice it...i copied the path from explorer...thanks again