# required_once issue in Google API Client for PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, include-path, google-api-php-client, require-once

I have been trying to import/include file in my php script file and somehow it is not working. I know this `require_once` question has been asked so many times [ [1. require_once with subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049592/require-once-with-subfolders) , [2. require_once() cant find the include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561442/require-once-cant-find-the-include-path), [3. Using require_once for up directory not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184223/using-require-once-for-up-directory-not-working)] but none of them seemed to be working for me.

Blow picture will explain what I am trying to do clearly:
[image]

What I tried and errors:

### Attempt 1

```
require_once(__DIR__.'GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php');
echo 'Hey1';  //Does not echo this, means something went wrong above.
require_once(__DIR__.'GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php');
echo 'Hey2';
```

[image]

Error I get:

[image]

### Attempt 2 (Fixed issue of attempt 1 but raised another issue.)

So I decided to use absolute path :

```
include '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php';
echo 'Hey1';
include '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php';
echo 'Hey2';
```

Gives me error in Client.php file:

```
`Warning: require_once(/Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php on line 18`

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php on line 18`

Investigating upon I found Client.php (of Google APIs Client Library for PHP) has these lines which are actually present:

require_once 'Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php';  // <-- Can't find
require_once 'Google/Cache/File.php';   // <-- Can't find
require_once 'Google/Cache/Memcache.php';  // <-- Can't find
```

[image]

I do not what is going wrong here. Fixed attempt 1's issue but now errors are in google's own library which I do not know how to overcome. I assume I am doing something silly which I can not figure out. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Copy the Google Directory and all subdirectories put it in the Same directory as your PHP file you are trying to run.  This might help http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Comment: I will check it out and comment. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @DaImTo : It seems there is an issue with Library files. `Warning: require_once(Google/Auth/OAuth2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php on line 18`. 
Well OAuth2.php and AssertionCredentials.php are in the same directory under **Auth** and it tries to look in to wrong directory using `require_once "Google/Auth/OAuth2.php";` in **AssertionCredentials.php**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you ever dumped `__DIR__`? Usually there's no `/` at the end. So you would have to change your code to this:

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php');
                      ^
```

I just checked in your [screen shot with the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Z1J.png),  there's no / at the end.

`/Applications/MAMP/htdocsGoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php`
instead of `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GoogleClientApi/src/Google/Client.php`

Comment: I think __DIR__ gives you `/currentDuirectoryPath/` so I think no / needed. Still giving it a try

Comment: Thanks to the downvoter downvoting my correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to **set the include path to include the root directory (src folder)** using this line :

```
set_include_path("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GoogleClientApi/src/");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Client.php

```
set_include_path(__DIR__.'/../' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```